# How to make Code Igniter ajax request URL appear to browser URL.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using `code-igniter` `framework`. When i click or select following `panel1` any option, each click and select event i made as to call Ajax function and user information will appear to `panel2` `DIV` tag. 
I can't see full URL on my address bar. How to display the ajax request URL on the browser address bar.

[image]

```
var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/userinfo/' + gender + '/' + age_min + '/' + age_max;
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxUrl,
  dataType: "JSON",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(retdata) {


  });
```

Comment: do you want to show the url of that page which load in `panel2` ?

Comment: I guess you need here to manage browser history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of articles, even here in SO, that explain how to change the url of the adress bar wihtout refreshing the page( while performing an ajax call for instance). The base idea is to use HTML5 History API (the pushState()).  Something like:

```
var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/userinfo/' + gender + '/' + age_min + '/' + age_max;
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxUrl,
  dataType: "JSON",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(retdata) {

   window.history.pushState({"html":retdata.html,"pageTitle":retdata.pageTitle},"", ajaxUrl);
  });
```

There is also a polyfill for this libaray called history.js for old browsers.

Comment: work perfectly. But when i copy that URL and past in to new window i can see only array data set. How to avoid this.

Comment: Hi @GeethWelagedara, I don't see your point, could you please show me what do you mean by an `array data set`. anyways, each window has its own history stack. I just gave you the idea behind and of course you need first read about the HTML5 History API to avoid other possible issues.

Comment: As my page, panel 2 data comes from database and home page load all user data. according to ajax url  with parameters data comes to $("#maindiv").append(userinfo);

Comment: Honnestly, I don't fully get your point. But there is another thing I suspect, that can cause you such issue (or other possible issues). It is the way you are constructing your urls. You certainly have a routing mechanism (in client and server side) that you are not using. For the server side, I am sure you have a routing system with codeigniter. So please avoid mixing php with javascript.`var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/userinfo/' + gender + '/' + age_min + '/' + age_max;` is not nice code